# How to display div id value in form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show JavaScript output value in form input.Bellow my div which output the value.

```
<div id="geo" class="geolocation_data"></div>
```

But I want to show in input box. I tried bellow code but not showing any

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Please type a location" class="form-control input-lg noredius geolocation_data" value="" id="geo">
```

Comment: Id must be unique, don't use same id for both div and input

Comment: You should not have duplicate id attributes in web page...Try `$('input[type="text"].geolocation_data').val(YOUR_VALUE)`

Comment: i dont want to display div it will removed.

Comment: please include your javascript code

Comment: i am getting result when i use <div id="geo" class="geolocation_data"></div> but i dont want to use Div same need to show in input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Please type a location" class="form-control input-lg noredius geolocation_data" value="" id="geo">
```

You should use the below Javascript code to populate the textbox with some value:

```
document.getElementById("geo").value= Your_variable_containing_the_value;
```

Comment: function updatePage() {
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
  var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = '' + response;
 }
}

Comment: function updatePage() { 
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
  { 
   var response = xmlHttp.responseText;    
   document.getElementById("geo").value = response;
  } 
 }

And remove your DIV tag and just put the text element

Comment: document.getElementById("geo").value = response;  helped to work thank  you